# Eclipse error after moving project (No resource found that matches the given name)

Tags: android, eclipse, buildpath

I had a perfectly working project of an app on android. It uses actionbarsherlock. I moved using the refactor menu in eclipse to another folder and now I have problems with the styles.xml

No resource found that matches the given name 'windowActionBarOverlay'

As I said, the project worked well before moving it so I think it has something to do with the build path.

Restoring it to the previous folder doesn't fix the problem.

Thanks a lot!

**Styles.xml**

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
<style name="PagerTabStripText">
      <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>

 </style>
 <style name="btnStyleBeige" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
       <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
       <item name="android:gravity">center</item>



       <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_beige</item>
       <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```